# ReflectionException - Class ... does not exist

Tags: laravel, exception, reflection

My project (laravel app) was working fine until I Installed the latest version of xampp (php 7.4) then when I login to my app , I get this error

```
ReflectionException
Class App\Repositories\StatsRepository does not exist
```

StatsRepository (dependency injection) is injected in my StatsController

```
class StatsController extends Controller
{
    private $statsRepository;

    public function __construct(StatsRepository $statsRepository)
    {
        $this->statsRepository = $statsRepository;
```

I changed NOTHING in my code
I already tested with :

1. composer dump-autoload
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan optimize
   ... etc

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your file permissions changed with the xampp update.

Comment: I uninstalled the previous version before Installing the latest one , already did the same before but with no similar issues

Comment: So have you looked at the file permissions?

Comment: I have full access (Admin) and I execute xampp as admin

Comment: Yes you might, but your application may not be running as root. So if you look at your file/folder ownership and permissions, you may find that something has changed.

Comment: I ended up with deleting the directory and cloning it again from the remote repository